# how do we get information about All users who can read or update a certain document in lotusnotes

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, opencmis

Iam trying to get details of all users who can read or update a certain document in Lotusnotes from `AclServiceUtils.getAcl()`.

Here iam using REST based Domino Access Services interface to access Domino server.

can anyone reply me with a solution.

Comment: This is a duplicate question to http://stackoverflow.com/q/36300398/2065611.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meaning of java.lang.ClassCastException: someClass incompatible with someClass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352550/meaning-of-java-lang-classcastexception-someclass-incompatible-with-someclass)